In swift, one predicate in a compound predicate is causing an exception: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (altWords CONTAINS[c] "a")'
I have a compoundPredicate:
searchPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [greekKeyPredicate, englishKeyPredicate, wordNumberPredicate, altWordsPredicate, wordImagePredicate])

The altWords predicate results in this exception:
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (altWords CONTAINS[c] "a")'


My predicates are:
 let greekKeyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "greekWord CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString)
        let englishKeyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "englishWord CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString)
        let wordNumberPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "wordNumber = %i", searchString)
        let wordImagePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "wordImage CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString)
        let altWordsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "altWords CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString)


If I remove the altWordsPredicate, all works ok.
The entity attribute shows:

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the predicate. Also, is there a swifter way to implement this?
By removing the altWords predicate, the project works as I would expect. By having altWords as the only predicate, I still get the crash.
I have searched SO for similar questions, but can find no results for NSCompoundPredicates.

It seems good to me and should work. Rewrite the predicate from scratch as there might be a hidden character maybe? A little more safer to write them is to use #keyPath: NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[c] %@", argumentArray: [#keyPath(MyEntity.wordImage), searchString]) and you'd avoid then a possible typo on the property name.

no joy though..

Did you do a migration on your Database? Is this the last version of it? Can you test on a "fresh install"?

Or if the property is new then maybe all you need is to clean the build folder and rebuild (possibly also removing the apps folder in DerivedData)

As I'm in early testing, I don't migrate the DB. I've deleted the app from my devices and simulators and clean the project. I'm also going to see if there is a data problem, but I appreciate any more thing to check.
